# How to put logo next to the title at same height in vue with bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

```js
export default {
  name: 'Sidebar'
};
```

```css
#logo {
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  border: none;
}

.nav-item a {
  color: #83888c;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.nav-item {
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.data-uri-logo1 {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cg id='backup_24px'%3E%3Cpath id='icon/action/backup_24px' fill-rule='evenodd' clip-rule='evenodd' d='M19.35 10.04C18.67 6.59 15.64 4 12 4C9.10999 4 6.59998 5.64001 5.34998 8.04001C2.33997 8.35999 0 10.91 0 14C0 17.31 2.68994 20 6 20H19C21.76 20 24 17.76 24 15C24 12.36 21.95 10.22 19.35 10.04ZM19 18H6C3.79004 18 2 16.21 2 14C2 11.95 3.53003 10.24 5.56006 10.03L6.63 9.92001L7.13 8.97C8.07996 7.14001 9.93994 6 12 6C14.62 6 16.88 7.85999 17.39 10.43L17.6899 11.93L19.22 12.04C20.78 12.14 22 13.45 22 15C22 16.65 20.65 18 19 18ZM10.55 13H8L12 9L16 13H13.45V16H10.55V13Z' fill='black' fill-opacity='0.54'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.title-section {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <b-sidebar id="sidebar" aria-label="Sidebar " no-header width="300px">
            <template #footer="{ hide }">
                <b-button size="sm">Collapse</b-button>
                <b-button size="sm" @click="hide">Logout</b-button>
            </template>

<div>
  <b-img id="logo" :src="require('./../assets/logo.png')" thumbnail></b-img>
</div>

<div>
  <b-nav vertical>
    <div class="title-section">
      <div class="data-uri-logo1"></div>
      <b-nav-item>title1</b-nav-item>
    </div>
    <div class="title-section">
      <div class="data-uri-logo1"></div>
      <b-nav-item>title2</b-nav-item>
    </div>
    <div class="title-section">
      <div class="data-uri-logo1"></div>
      <b-nav-item>title3</b-nav-item>
    </div>
    <div class="title-section">
      <div class="data-uri-logo1"></div>
      <b-nav-item>title4</b-nav-item>
    </div>
  </b-nav>
</div>
</b-sidebar>
</div>
</template>
```

Here is what I got so far:

[image]

I am trying to get the same behavior as the following picture.

[image]

I am using flexbox to achieve my goal but it does not work as I expected. Thanks for any help! What is logic to achieve my goal? `b-nav-item` in the dom tree is just a `<li>` element with a tag. I also try to add images directly into the `b-nav-item tag`, however, it will not render correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#logo {
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    border: none;
}
.nav-item a {
    color: #83888c;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.nav-item {
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.data-uri-logo1 {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cg id='backup_24px'%3E%3Cpath id='icon/action/backup_24px' fill-rule='evenodd' clip-rule='evenodd' d='M19.35 10.04C18.67 6.59 15.64 4 12 4C9.10999 4 6.59998 5.64001 5.34998 8.04001C2.33997 8.35999 0 10.91 0 14C0 17.31 2.68994 20 6 20H19C21.76 20 24 17.76 24 15C24 12.36 21.95 10.22 19.35 10.04ZM19 18H6C3.79004 18 2 16.21 2 14C2 11.95 3.53003 10.24 5.56006 10.03L6.63 9.92001L7.13 8.97C8.07996 7.14001 9.93994 6 12 6C14.62 6 16.88 7.85999 17.39 10.43L17.6899 11.93L19.22 12.04C20.78 12.14 22 13.45 22 15C22 16.65 20.65 18 19 18ZM10.55 13H8L12 9L16 13H13.45V16H10.55V13Z' fill='black' fill-opacity='0.54'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    height: 2rem;
    width: 2rem;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    justify-content: space-around;
    
    /* -> */ background-position: center;
}

.title-section {
    display: flex;
    
    /* -> */ align-items: center;
}
```

```html
    <div>
        <b-sidebar id="sidebar" aria-label="Sidebar " no-header width="300px">
            <template #footer="{ hide }">
                <b-button size="sm">Collapse</b-button>
                <b-button size="sm" @click="hide">Logout</b-button>
            </template>

            <div>
                <b-img
                    id="logo"
                    :src="require('./../assets/logo.png')"
                    thumbnail
                ></b-img>
            </div>

            <div>
                <b-nav vertical>
                    <div class="title-section">
                        <div class="data-uri-logo1"></div>
                        <b-nav-item>title1</b-nav-item>
                    </div>
                    <div class="title-section">
                        <div class="data-uri-logo1"></div>
                        <b-nav-item>title2</b-nav-item>
                    </div>
                    <div class="title-section">
                        <div class="data-uri-logo1"></div>
                        <b-nav-item>title3</b-nav-item>
                    </div>
                    <div class="title-section">
                        <div class="data-uri-logo1"></div>
                        <b-nav-item>title4</b-nav-item>
                    </div>
                </b-nav>
            </div>
        </b-sidebar>
    </div>
```

Of course, first of all, you average the background image.

`/* -> */ background-position: center;`

After that, since the parent surrounding the image and text is in flex structure, we center the contents.

`/* -> */ align-items: center;`

All codes are available in the snippet above.